# Не срабатывает функция в Django

Tags: django

Ребята, не могу въехать, почему функция не отрабатывает. 
Строка из HTML:

```
<a href="/articles/addlike/{{ article.id }}/"><img src="{% static "like.jpg" %}" width="25px" height="25px"></a>{{ article.article_likes }}
```

URL pattern:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
                url(r'^1/', views.basic_one),
                url(r'^articles/all/$', views.articles),
                url(r'^articles/get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', views.article),
                url(r'^', views.articles),
                url(r'^articles/addlike/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', views.addlike, name='addlike'),
                url(r'^articles/addcomment/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', views.addcomment),
              ]
```

Вьюха:

```
def addlike(request, article_id):
    try:
        article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
        article.article_likes += 1 #в модели поле models.IntegerField(default=0)
        article.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return redirect('/')
```

Ошибок не выдает, после нажатия в браузере на иконку лайка, которая должна увеличивать значение в БД на 1, всё остается на том же месте, значение в БД не меняется, в адресной строке сслыка принимет вид http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/addlike/1/ и всё...Куда капать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Покажи весь urls.py, скорее всего у тебя перехватывается урл в диспетчере из-за отсутствия $ в конце строки и не попадает в нужное вью.

Вью можно вообще упростить

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def addlike(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, article_id)
    article.article_likes += 1
    article.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

В диспетчере можно назвать url, что бы в html избежать хардкода в ссылках

```
url(r'^articles/addlike/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', views.addlike, name="add_like")
```

В шаблоне:

```
<a href="{% url add_like article_id %}">
```

Comment: Весь список урлов:urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^1/', views.basic_one),
    url(r'^articles/all/$', views.articles),
    url(r'^articles/get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', views.article),
    url(r'^', views.articles),
    url(r'^articles/addlike/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', views.addlike, name='addlike'),
    url(r'^articles/addcomment/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', views.addcomment),
]

Comment: я хз как нормально отформатировать код в комментарии...сори

Comment: попробуй поменять 

url(r'^', views.articles), 

на 

url(r'^$', views.articles),

Comment: Заработало!! Дружище, спасибо тебе огромное))